# How is it possible that the function of the test page works, but it does not go live?

Tags: ajax, wp-config

I want to load the new entries without reloading the page.
I found a great solution for:
The ajax script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $('#content').fadeOut("fast").load('http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/new.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }, 10000);

    });
</script>
```

And the php:

```
<?php require_once("wp-blog-header.php"); ?>
<div id="content" <?php cyberchimps_filter_content_class(); ?>>

        <?php do_action( 'cyberchimps_before_content'); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php elseif ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'cyberchimps_after_content'); ?>

    </div>
```

However, this is a special feature that works perfectly here:
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/test/
However, the main page refuses to load new entries, I do not understand the reason for this, as we use everything the same.

Comment: Start by checking the home page for script errors. There are lots of them.

Comment: Which may be the most serious, which hangs in the function?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/new.php. Origin http://www.neocsatblog.mblx.hu is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` You have a cross domain issue which needs to be solved. Using jQuery's load() to pull in cross-domain requests is problematic. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889001/jquery-cross-domain-load-self-constructing-widget

Comment: That's just the crap in the chat, you think if you turn it off and work normally? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your script to this since you're not *actually* running a cross-browser request:

```
<script>
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
      $('#content').fadeOut("fast").load('/new.php').fadeIn("fast");
      $("#content .span9 article").unwrap();
    }, 10000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

UPDATE: Wrapped in WP-friendly jQuery no-conflict code...

Comment: Okay now, this part works, but somehow override the CSS and therefore the content of shrinking

Comment: Any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Yes. That's because it's filling `#content` with `#content` - you'll need to either change what new.php outputs (and get rid of the wrapping `#content` div), or change load with the parent.

Comment: I'm verry new bie in programing,can you share with me the script?

Comment: That makes things a little tricky, but let's try (immediately after your jQuery load line in the script) $("#content1 article").unwrap(); and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I tryed this ways:

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("#content1 article").unwrap();
</script>
And this way:
`
<script>
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
      $('#content').fadeOut("fast").load('/new.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }, 10000);
  });
$("#content1 article").unwrap();
})(jQuery);
</script>
But unfortunately none of them work.
WHat do i wrong? :D

Comment: I'm editing my original code answer now to reflect the new code.

Comment: Already torment myself for a while in this function: D

Comment: I replaced the updated version, but it still got the error.

Comment: I just made another edit. It appears your ajax content was a little less predictable than I thought.

Comment: Now,do nothing :D

Comment: Do you think it would be simple css is an important indicator to retain the width?

Comment: I restored the oldered version,and i have a very intrested bug.
When i selected a page(example on the menu),the page is gone in some second,and the script redirect the post page :O

Comment: Okey i resolved this.
So this script not like hader place,just the index.php.
And i add !important atribut for the div witdh,like this:
.span9{width:834px !important;}

Answer (score 1):

WordPress loads jQuery in [NoConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Do not use `$`. Use `jQuery` or [one of the other solutions in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers), like this one:

```
(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
})(jQuery);
```

Nothing will work until you sort that out.

Comment: Not sure I agree with "nothing will work until you sort that out" but it's certainly the best practice - updated my answer to reflect that note.

Comment: Unless you've loaded your own jQuery, or manipulated/added the `$` object in some way, the jQuery dependent Javascript will not work. You will get a `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I am not sure what's not to agree with.

Comment: Correct. And I'm not condoning the practice of short circuiting WP's jQuery behaviors, but that doesn't mean it's not reasonably common practice and - in fact - in this case it was.