# Bootstrap collapse in custom WordPress widget

Tags: plugin-development, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a custom widget and using Bootstrap 3 for the styling. I want to implement an accordion has seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). However, I cannot get it to work correctly. I am including transition.js, collapse.js and component-animations.scss in my calls to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_styles`. Also I have deregistered the WP included jQuery and registered the version included with Bootstrap. I either get one of two scenarios. Scenario one is nothing works at all. All scripts are being called correctly and in the right order according to Chrome Dev Tools. Scenario two is I can get it work, but only once. My thinking it is some sort of conflict. Here is my markup: (I'm not worried about the actual widget functionality right now, just trying to get the UI to work).

```
<div class='ws-business-info accordion-group' id="ws-accordion">
  <div class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ws-accordion" href="#monday">
                Monday
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div> <!-- panel title -->
    <div class='panel collapse in' id='monday'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mondayStart'); ?>">Open</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mondayStart'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mondayStart'); ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-3'>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mondayEnd'); ?>">Close</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mondayEnd'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mondayEnd'); ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-3'>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mondayEnd'); ?>"><p>Closed</p></label><br>
                <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mondayClosed'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mondayClosed'); ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel body-->
    </div><!-- panel collapse -->
</div> <!-- panel default -->
```

That markup is repeated for each day of the week. Here is scenario one javascript:

```
 $('.collapse').collapse();
```

and here is scenario two javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.panel-title a').click(function() {
           $('.collapse').collapse('toggle');
       });
  });
```

Comment: Sounds like you are including two versions of jQuery. That is a good way to cause trouble, if that is the case.

Comment: Nah, I deregistered the WP included jQuery so only one version of jQuery is being loaded.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116853/21376

Comment: Yeah, I already tried all that. I think there is a conflict in the bootstrap transition.js or collapse.js